# scsslint ColorVariable and sass palettes

Tags: css, sass, csslint, scss-lint

I have a problem with scsslint in this variable

> ColorVariable: Color literals like `blue` should only be used in
>   variable declarations; they should be referred to via variable
>   everywhere else.

I have this sass palette:

```
 $color-palettes: (
        blue: (
            light    : lighten($grey, 6%),
            base     : $grey,
        ),
    );


//using sass palettes
p {
  color: palette(blue);
}

//wrong way
p {
    color:blue;
}

// right way by scsslint I totally agree

// creating the variable
$blue:#0055FF;

p {
    color:$blue;
}
```

the problem is I am passing the value palette(blue); and this make scsslint complain about blue.

I know I can change the scss-lint.yml to false ans solve that

```
ColorVariable:
    enabled: false
```

but the problem I want avoid bad practices like:

```
p {
    color:blue;
}

p {
    color:white;
}
```

so in that case what the best I should do? to Keep Using the validation in my file jumping some classes that ColorVariable?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you might want to look at alternate ways of implementing a colour palette with sass maps + function: http://codepen.io/erskine/pen/wLclB?editors=010 instead?

Comment: thanks , instead  purple or grey can i use names like: footer header content?

Comment: Yes you can swap the names out. But for this purpose of styling by the element, I've personally find it more flexible to have another layer of abstraction on top of that i.e a map for colors, and a map for elements that reference the color map. This way you can use both colors and elements.

Comment: can you give to me a small example to a map for elements ? or just a link, thanks Joel